# Cannot find altitude parameter in Navigator geolocation while capturing device location need to know what sensor is used to detect location GPS/Wifi

Tags: javascript, geolocation, google-geolocation, ip-geolocation, w3c-geolocation

I'm using [Navigator geolocation property](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-navigator-geolocation-property/) to detect User's device location. In the return object I'm receiving a parameter 'coords', according to which I'm identifying what is the sensor used to determine user's location. GPS, Wifi, or IP, (n/w triangulation).

**This wasn't an issue before and it was working fine but now altitude and altitudeAccuracy is null**

Any suggestions that could help me determine what is to be done to determine how the location was captured would help.

```
input: navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(response){console.log(response);})
Output: {
    Object {
      coords: Object {
        accuracy: 30
        altitude: null
        altitudeAccuracy: null
        heading: null
        latitude: 28.492950699999998
        longitude: 77.081955
        speed: null
      }
      timestamp: 1579076825120
    }
```

Now the issue is with other devices than iPhones. I'm receiving the altitude and altitudeAccuracy parameters in Apple Devices.

```
Output in iPhone: 
Object {
    coords: Object {
        accuracy: 65
        altitude: 227.05543518066406
        altitudeAccuracy: 10
        floorLevel: null
        heading: null
        latitude: 28.492904178327134
        longitude: 77.08190460816849
        speed: null
      }
      timestamp: 1579074376596
    }
```

**So if there is any other way I can detect whether GPS is used to capture device location or it was captured using wifi/IP that would serve my use-case.**

Comment: according to [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GeolocationCoordinates) - *This value can be null if the **implementation** cannot provide the data* - but, what Apple Devices work for you?

Comment: I get `altitude: null` too, for Chrome 79 on W10

Comment: Apple device's altitude shows on Chrome not on Safari. I am testing on iPhone XS. Anyway, before it was constant for all mobile devices(I had tested for, Samsung, Apple, OnePlus etc.), last week onwards, it has been giving null for altitude. @JaromandaX

Comment: Also, yes, you are supposed to get null for W10, or systems not having a GPS sensor, @CertainPerformance Issue is with mobile devices for which it was resulting in a value before. Any other alternative that can be provided to determine which sensor is being used for capturing the location on the user's device? Wifi, IP, or GPS